# async all the way down VS async on top level

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

Which one of the following is the best way of using async await.

**Option 1**: Async await in all the functions

```
public async Task A()
{
   await B();
   //some code
}

public async Task<bool> B()
{
   var result= await C(); 
   //some code
   return result; 
}

public Task<bool> C()
{ 
   // not implemnted
}
```

OR

**Option 2**: Async await in only the top level function

```
 public async Task A()
    {
       await B();
       //some code
    }

    public async Task<bool> B()
    {
        var result= C().Result; 
        //some code
        return result; 

    }

    public Task<bool> C()
    { 
       // not implemnted
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Option 1 is the correct way to do it and 2 should not be done. If you are using async anywhere in your callstack you should never call `.Result` or `.Wait()` on a task in your code. If you do you it is very likely you will end up deadlocking your program.

UPDATE: on a side note, if the code in function B does not rely on being the same thread that started the function (no UI work) the "best" way to do it would be

```
public async Task A()
{
   await B();
   //some code that interacts with the UI
}

public async Task<bool> B()
{
   var result= await C().ConfigureAwait(false); 
   //some code does does not interact with the UI
   return result; 
}

public Task<bool> C()
{ 
   // not implemnted
}
```

This lets the system use any available thread pool thread instead of waiting for the Synchronization context to become available when the continuation is run.

Comment: Edited my question...as in function B I have to do some processing based on the result

Comment: Does the code in function B rely on the UI in any way? I updated my answer to show a better way if it does not.

Comment: Nope.. No UI context is required

Comment: If you don't need to be on the same context later on in the code you should try to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` wherever you can then.

Comment: All asycn await creates state machine..don't you think if I'll use async await in every function they all will create there own state machines and will be doing the same thing...

Comment: Yes, there is a overhead due to the state machine of async/await, but if you don't do it you can deadlock your code if you are on a syncronisation context. Run your option 2 example in a program with a UI thead, just add a `await Task.Yield()` to C to make it yield control back to the caller. You will have a deadlock on the `await B();` line.

Comment: Also, doing `await` does not generate the state machine, adding `async` to the function definiation does. So your option 2 example has the state machine anyway.

Comment: await needs async anyway so they both go together....:) So to summarize according to you blocking async code is similar to await a blocking code..right..?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I think the answer might be yes? What I am trying to say is you should never syncronously block on a task if there is async code involved anywhere above or below you in the call chain.

Comment: What i meant was if I have a function A waiting(.Result) for function B (async) -> this arrangment will block the thread...right?

Comment: The opposite will also block the thread A(async) awaiting for B(waiting for other task using .Result)